# What is the sentence constituents of "on business"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Mr.Black went to town ***on business***.  What is the sentence constituents of "on business"?

Answer (score 2):

In normal grammar terminology "on business" is an adverbial phrase (word group) and an adverbial sentence part, indicating the reason why Mr Black went to town. I don't use and know grammar terminology that works with the terms constituents. I know only word classes, parts of a word group, word groups and parts of a sentence.